# VarianceThreshold Function For Data Cleansing

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following function that I want to use to see how many features are selected based on different Threshold values for the variance.

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VarianceThresholdSelector

```
  def varianceThreshold(df: DataFrame, thresholds: Seq[Threshold]): Seq[(Threshold, DataFrame)] = {
    thresholds.map(threshold => {
      val selector = new VarianceThresholdSelector()
        .setVarianceThreshold(threshold)
        .setFeaturesCol("features")
        .setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

      (threshold, selector.fit(df).transform(df))
    })
  }
```

So far so good. I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image: DataFrame]

Now my question is if col2 is the predictor variable, i.e., the value that I'm trying to predict, how can I then have all the other columns grouped so that I can pass that as a feature as such. For example., I came across this example from the Spark documentation:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VarianceThresholdSelector
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val data = Seq(
  (1, Vectors.dense(6.0, 7.0, 0.0, 7.0, 6.0, 0.0)),
  (2, Vectors.dense(0.0, 9.0, 6.0, 0.0, 5.0, 9.0)),
  (3, Vectors.dense(0.0, 9.0, 3.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0)),
  (4, Vectors.dense(0.0, 9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0)),
  (5, Vectors.dense(8.0, 9.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0)),
  (6, Vectors.dense(8.0, 9.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
)

val df = spark.createDataset(data).toDF("id", "features")

val selector = new VarianceThresholdSelector()
  .setVarianceThreshold(8.0)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

val result = selector.fit(df).transform(df)

println(s"Output: Features with variance lower than" +
  s" ${selector.getVarianceThreshold} are removed.")
result.show()
```

So for my example what will be the featureCol or rather how can I get my individual columns as a featuresCol array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get the effect that I wanted:

```
type Threshold = Double

import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VarianceThresholdSelector

def varianceThreshold(df: DataFrame, thresholds: Seq[Threshold]): Seq[(Threshold, DataFrame)] = {
  val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(df.columns.tail)
    .setOutputCol("features")
  val output = assembler.transform(df)
  thresholds.map(threshold => {
    val selector = new VarianceThresholdSelector()
      .setVarianceThreshold(threshold)
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

  (threshold, selector.fit(output).transform(output))
    
  })
}
```